# How to add text to a file foreach column using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a file like this

```
DeviceID     : 3
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZVLW1T0HMLH-000H1

DeviceID     : 0
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZNLN256HAJQ-000H7

DeviceID     : 1
FriendlyName : ST1000LM049-2GH172
```

And I have other file like this

```
DAY JUNE1=3
DAY JUNE2=0
DAY JUNE3=1
```

I want to apend second file to first file, to be like this

```
JUNE1
DeviceID     : 3
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZVLW1T0HMLH-000H1

JUNE2
DeviceID     : 0
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZNLN256HAJQ-000H7

JUNE3
DeviceID     : 1
FriendlyName : ST1000LM049-2GH172
```

I tried this

```
$file1 = Get-Content .\file1
$file2 = Get-Content .\file2
$output = $file, $file2 | Out-File .\outputfile.txt
```

my result is like this

```
DAY JUNE1=3
DAY JUNE2=0
DAY JUNE3=1

DeviceID     : 3
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZVLW1T0HMLH-000H1

DeviceID     : 0
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZNLN256HAJQ-000H7

DeviceID     : 1
FriendlyName : ST1000LM049-2GH172
```

My expectation, I can create a new file with my expectation output like I mentioned above. Please help any idea

### Updated

I tried this

```
$file1 = Get-Content .\file1
$file2 = Get-Content .\file2

$i=1
$arr=@()
Foreach($item in $file1)
{
$str= 'JUNE'+ $i + '=' + $item
$arr += $str
$i=$i+1
}
$arr | out-file Output.txt
```

It return me like this

```
JUNE1=
JUNE2=
JUNE3=DeviceID     : 0
JUNE5=FriendlyName : INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H SED
JUNE6=
JUNE7=DeviceID     : 1
JUNE8=FriendlyName : INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H
JUNE9=
JUNE10=DeviceID     : 2
JUNE11=FriendlyName : TOSHIBA DT01ACA100
JUNE12=
JUNE13=
JUNE14=
```

Comment: You need to parse each file, then combine the results, then create new formatted output. Take a look at [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: `$i = 0
$file2[$i] + "`r`n" + $file1[$i] + "`r`n" + $file1[$i + 1]
$i++` Its not a solution, but might be on the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the number of sections in file1 matches the number of lines in file2,
you could read file1 with the `-raw` parameter and
split after each empty line, similarly split the lines of file2 at space and equal sign:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\15\SO_57505745.ps1
$file1 = (Get-Content .\file1 -raw) -split '(?<=\n)\r?\n'
$file2 =  Get-Content .\file2

$arr = for($i=0;$i -lt $file1.Count;$i++){
    ($file2[$i] -split ' |=')[1]
     $file1[$i]
}
$arr #| out-file Output.txt
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\08\15\SO_57505745.ps1
JUNE1
DeviceID     : 3
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZVLW1T0HMLH-000H1

JUNE2
DeviceID     : 0
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZNLN256HAJQ-000H7

JUNE3
DeviceID     : 1
FriendlyName : ST1000LM049-2GH172
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the input files, I think you may need to match the values for the dates to the DeviceID's in the other file.

You can do that like this:

```
# read the devices as array of Hashtables
$hardware = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\devices.txt' -Raw).Trim() -split '\r?\n\r?\n' -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
# read the dates as Hashtable
$dates    = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\devicedates.txt' -Raw).Trim() -replace 'DAY\s*' | ConvertFrom-StringData

# build the output strings, matching the values for the dates with the DeviceID's
$result = foreach ($device in $hardware) {
    $dte = $dates.Keys | Where-Object { $dates[$_] -eq $device['DeviceID'] }

    # output as formatted string
    "$dte{0}DeviceID     : {1}{0}FriendlyName : {2}{0}" -f [Environment]::NewLine, $device['DeviceID'], $device['FriendlyName']
}

$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\devicescomplete.txt' -Force
```

Output:

> ```
> JUNE1
> DeviceID     : 3
> FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZVLW1T0HMLH-000H1
>
> JUNE2
> DeviceID     : 0
> FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZNLN256HAJQ-000H7
>
> JUNE3
> DeviceID     : 1
> FriendlyName : ST1000LM049-2GH172
> ```

Comment: Hi @Theo, thank you. I have one problem, how if I have more than 2 item not only DeviceID and FriendlyName? How do I add it?

Comment: @Job Simply add them to the 'devices' file and also to the output string.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks @Theo

Comment: Hi @Job ,  could you please check it out if you dont mind, my friend and I did homework and still stuck https://stackoverflow.com/q/57509091/11099245 Thanks

Comment: @Job If you mean you would like to sort the output on any of the devices properties, then just add `| Sort-Object { $_.DeviceID }` at the end of the line that starts with `$hardware = `. Here I'm using the `DeviceID` property, but you can sort on any property the devices have. If you want the sort to go the other way, append the  `-Descending` switch. [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object)